# Erro : java.io.IOException: Stream closed

Tags: java, exception, stream, serversocket

```
      try{
        URLPath = "xxxxx";
        URL url = new URL(URLPath);
        uc = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        uc.setReadTimeout(30000);//timeout set

        uc.connect();// connect


        fos = new FileOutputStream(savePath);
        InputStream in = uc.getInputStream();
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int Length = 0;
        long FinishedLenth = 0;

        while((Length = in.read(buffer)) > 0) {
            FinishedLenth = FinishedLenth + Length;
            fos.write(buffer, 0, Length);
        }
        in.close();
        uc.disconnect();

        fos.close();
      }
```

This is my download code.
And I have problem, when I download small file like 600mb ,
and no error happen.
But I download 2G up file size, and the error happened.

```
java.io.IOException: Stream closed
at java.io.BufferedInputStream.getBufIfOpen(Unknown Source)
at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$HttpInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$HttpInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$HttpInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$HttpInputStream.close(Unknown Source)
at Download_File.downloadFile(Download_File.java:66)
at downloadFileFunctionThread.run(downloadFileFunctionThread.java:116)
```

This is error message, I google the error message.
I find some solution is socket close problem.
But the error happened when download large size file.
So I don't know how to solve the problem.
Thanks All.

Comment: "When I download a small file like 600mb" what. Are you sure you typed that properly?

Answer (score 2):

probably problem is with

```
uc.setReadTimeout(30000);//timeout set
```

For a larger file your connection may getting timedout , give a value higher than the duration requiered to download your file or dont specify one.

Comment: But I already download the file.The download size is correct.And the error happened.

Comment: Yes, I have has the same error and solved my problem, thanks.